# WHERE-IN statement: error while executing SQL query on database: row value misused

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, where-clause

I get this error

> Error while executing SQL query on database X: row value misused

for the following query pattern:

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table
WHERE (field1, field2) IN (('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'))
```

Any hints on what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Row Value Comparisons](https://www.sqlite.org/rowvalue.html#row_value_comparisons):

> For a row-value IN operator, the left-hand side (hereafter "LHS") can
> be either a parenthesized list of values or a subquery with multiple
> columns. But the right-hand side (hereafter "RHS") **must be a subquery**
> **expression**.

In your case `(('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'))` is not a subquery expression.

What you can do is create a CTE that returns the row values in the parentheses and use a subquery that selects from that CTE:

```
WITH cte(field1, field2) AS (VALUES ('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'))
SELECT *
FROM some_table
WHERE (field1, field2) IN (SELECT field1, field2 FROM cte)
```

Or simpler:

```
WITH cte(field1, field2) AS (VALUES ('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'))
SELECT *
FROM some_table
WHERE (field1, field2) IN cte
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=4193a358ab0aa36444a6a2f937c1aaad).